# Combining series into pandas dataframes ignoring the indices

Tags: pandas, dataframe, z-index, series

I have two series namely x and y which were created by extracting the values related to a list of indices.

x:

| Index | Timestamp |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-11-16 13:00:00 |
| 143 | 2022-11-17 13:48:00 |

y:

| Index | Timestamp |
| --- | --- |
| 37 | 2022-11-16 19:13:00 |
| 157 | 2022-11-17 16:21:00 |

I want to combine these two series into a pandas dataframe.
I used the following code for that.

```
x = pd.concat([Rising_Timestamp, Falling_Timestamp], ignore_index=True, axis=1)
```

But this creates Nan because of the indexes are different in the two series.

Preferred output:

| start | End |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-11-16 13:00:00 | 2022-11-16 19:13:00 |
| 2022-11-17 13:48:00 | 2022-11-17 16:21:00 |

How can I do this in pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x = x.reset_index(drop=True)
y = y.reset_index(drop=True)
df = pd.concat([x, y], axis=1)
```

Note that this will still produce `NaN` values if the series aren't the same length. Also, it assumes that your data is aligned as you expect it to be.

Comment: This perfectly works as my series are of the same length.

Comment: Can I know how to change the Column names here. Both appears as Timestamp in mine and I can't change it using rename function

Comment: try the `keys` parameter in pd.concat -- so for your case, something like 
`df = pd.concat([x, y], axis=1, keys=[start, end])`